# Toggle code not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my code for a class called Toggle, that toggles multiple components in my site. The HTML has a data attribute on it called data-expand-content, and the css is set up to say that when data-expand-content is true, display: block or whatever this content. And the JS is what toggles the data attribute on click. It works fine on all browsers except for IE11, please help me figure out what is wrong?

Thanks!

Here's the JS

```
class Toggle {
    constructor(control, el) {
        const toggleLink = document.querySelector('.primary-nav__toggle-link');
        control = document.querySelector(control);
        el = document.querySelector(el);
        if(el) {
            control.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                if(el.dataset.expandContent == "false") {
                    el.dataset.expandContent = "true"
                    if(e.target == document.querySelector('.primary-nav__toggle-icon')) {
                        document.querySelector('.primary-nav__toggle-icon').setAttribute('src', '../assets/close-menu.svg');
                    }
                } else {
                    el.dataset.expandContent = "false";
                    if(e.target == document.querySelector('.primary-nav__toggle-icon')) {
                        document.querySelector('.primary-nav__toggle-icon').setAttribute('src', '../assets/burger-menu.svg');
                    }
                }
            })
        }   
    }
}

// new instances of class that get passed a control and a the element that gets toggled
const menu = new Toggle('.primary-nav__toggle-link', '#primary-nav');
const bannerEl = new Toggle('.banner', '.banner');
```

Comment: How is the question related to React? Are you using the code as is, or are you transpiling it to ES5 first?

Comment: Whoops! Shouldnt have added react there, I am using react in this same project, but it does not relate to this question. And yes, I am using Babel.